# How to implement a compare-operator for a struct/class of strings?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a class which represents a decomposed URL.

```
class URL
{
    std::string proto_;
    std::string host_;
    /* other fields */
};
```

(for example, `proto_` can be http, https, ldap; `host_` can be localhost:1234, google.com).

The real, meaningful value to be compared is of course the composed URL. But constructing it is expensive and I'd like to use this class a key-type for a `std::map`.

How can I implement a `operator<()` for this class in an efficient way? How  to combine the comparison of distinct objects, which are in fact forming a whole, logically?

I tried using `std::tie` but the results are not as I expected.

As requested per comments

Here is what I'm currently doing (which works as expected):

```
friend bool operator<(const uri &l, const uri &r)
{
    std::string ls = l.proto_ + l.host_;
    std::string rs = r.proto_ + r.host_;
    return ls < rs;
}
```

Comment: Lexicographically. Compare the first field. If equal, compare the second field, etc.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, the output you expect to see, and the actual output.

Comment: Use `std::tie` but without bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class URL
{
    std::string proto_;
    std::string host_;
    /* other fields */
public:
    bool operator<(const URL& o) const {
        if (proto_ != o.proto_)
            return proto_ < o.proto_;
        if (host_ != o.host_)
            return host_ < o.host_;
        return false;
    }
};
```

The compare function should satisfy the [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept.

This also works well, too:

```
    bool operator<(const URL& o) const {
        return std::tie(proto_, host_) < std::tie(o.proto_, o.host_);
    }
```

or:

```
class URL
{
    std::string proto_;
    std::string host_;
    /* other fields */
public:
    bool operator<(const URL& o) const {
        return tie() < o.tie();
    }
    /* std::tuple<std::string&, std::string&> */
    auto tie() {
        return std::tie(proto_, host_);
    }
    auto tie() const {
        return std::tie(proto_, host_);
    }
};
```

with C++11 and without C++14 you will need this:

```
auto tie() -> decltype(std::tie(proto_, host_)){
    return std::tie(proto_, host_);
}
auto tie() const -> decltype(std::tie(proto_, host_)) {
    return std::tie(proto_, host_);
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yB0cuE8HjcSOBr9R)

Comment: Might as well use `std::tie` for shorter, less error-prone code.

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping the `std::tie` call in a member function, to avoid repeating yourself. Less of a chance to mix up parameter order when adding new ones.

Comment: @StoryTeller how is the prototype of this member?

Comment: @PatrickB. I'd just use [`auto` type deduction for it](http://ideone.com/qiIrbb) :)